# combine.self="override" doesn't seem to work

Tags: maven

I use parent and child POMs in my project:

Parent POM:

```xml
<pluginManagement>  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                       ...
                    <configuration>
                           ...
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <extensionArgs>
                                    <extensionArg>-XNullable</extensionArg>
                                    <arg>-encoding</arg>
                                    <arg>UTF-8</arg>
                                </extensionArgs>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

My goal in the child POM is to remove the `<extensionArg>-XNullable</extensionArg>` argument.

I tried this by using the `combine.self="override"` attribute:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <xsdOptions>
                    <xsdOption>
                        <extensionArgs combine.self="override">
                            <arg>-encoding</arg>
                            <arg>UTF-8</arg>
                        </extensionArgs>
                    </xsdOption>
                </xsdOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But this doesn't work. The effective configuration is still:

```xml
  <xsdOptions>
    <xsdOption>
      <extensionArgs combine.self="override">
        <extensionArg>-XNullable</extensionArg>
        <arg>-encoding</arg>
        <arg>UTF-8</arg>
      </extensionArgs>
    </xsdOption>
  </xsdOptions>
```

Any ideas how can I remove `<extensionArg>-XNullable</extensionArg>` from the configuration during Maven merging process?

Maven: 3.3.3

Comment: Have you checked the configuration via `mvn -X ...`

Comment: Yes, see the last small snippet (the effective configuration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your parent POM, you are adding the `<extensionArg>-XNullable</extensionArg>` to the configuration on a specific execution of the plugin (inside the `<execution>` tag element). However, in your child POM, you are overriding the general configuration (i.e. the configuration not specific to any execution).

As a result, the configuration of that specific execution will not be overriden. You need to move the configuration of the plugin in the child POM inside a specific execution. Another possibility is to move the configuration of the parent POM to the general configuration instead of a execution-specific one.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.